# How do I change the name of a file once I have uploaded it to the Ubuntu One Cloud?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've uploaded some camera files to my Ubuntu One file repository and they have unreadable file names. Is there any way to change the name once the file is in the repository?

I guess I could download them, change the names, and re-upload them. I was just looking for a way to rename them on the site instead...

Answer (score 4):

You can just rename it on your local computer and it will be synced to the cloud.

Comment: The files were uploaded from the flash memory card of the camera and actually have the same unreadable names on the camera's flash. I haven't synced them yet. Are they going to be synced when I next log in? I thought I had to tell Ubuntu One which files to sync? (I've only uploaded these into a folder)

Answer (score 2):

Dale, once you upload them (I'm guessing you did so through the web ui), they will be downloaded to you desktop, which is where you can rename them.

We have not yet implemented rename on the website, it's recorded in this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/354168

Answer (score 0):

If they're just unreadable in the browser, then it might be a Ubuntu One display problem. Try downloading them on another computer if you can - if the file's name is right, then you're ok. Just have to wait for Ubuntu One to fix the interface display.

Comment: The files actually look the same in the browser as they do on the camera's flash.